# Как сделать колонки одинаковой высоты

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

```css
.compl2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.compl-block {
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: #e10886;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #e10886;
}

.compl__title2 {
  font-size: 35px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.compl2__text {
  padding-top: 0;
  border-top: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-transform: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.compl2__text span {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="compl2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters a">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <h2 class="compl__title2 compl-block">
          комплекс 1
        </h2>
        <p class="compl-block compl2__text">
          <span>ноги</span> полностью, <br> глубокое бикини, <br> ягодицы, пальцы ног
        </p>
        <p class="compl-block compl2__text compl2__text2">
          4500
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <h2 class="compl__title2 compl-block">
          комплекс 2
        </h2>
        <p class="compl-block compl2__text">
          <span>ноги</span> полностью, <br> глубокое бикини, <br> подмышечные <br>впадины, пальцы ног
        </p>
        <p class="compl-block compl2__text compl2__text2">
          4000
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <h2 class="compl__title2 compl-block">
          комплекс 1
        </h2>
        <p class="compl-block compl2__text">
          <span>глубокое</span> бикини, <br> подмышечные
          <br> впадины голени, с, коленом
        </p>
        <p class="compl-block compl2__text compl2__text2">
          3000
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <h2 class="compl__title2 compl-block">
          комплекс 1
        </h2>
        <p class="compl-block compl2__text">
          <span>глубокое</span> бикини, <br> подмышечные впадины
        </p>
        <p class="compl-block compl2__text compl2__text2">
          2100
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Использую бустрапп на десктопе колонки разной длины как сделать чтобы независимо от текста они были одинаковой высоты 
Написал же на **ДЕСКТОПЕ** колонки разной **ВЫСОТЫ** 
Почему ставите дизлайки ?

Comment: увидел вопрос в списке, открыл, увидел разметку, ничего не понял, закрыл. если Вы хотите получить помощь то напишите вопрос так что бы он был понятен человеку со стороны...

Comment: @Bald спасибо сейчас исправлю

Comment: @Bald посмотрите пожалуйста я исправился ?

Comment: да, сейчас вопрос стал более понятен

Comment: возможно Вам поможет [flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/)

Comment: @Bald не могу сетку boostrapa мешает

Comment: относитесь к минусам проще

Comment: @Bald спасибо, буду учиться :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью jQuery, например (выравниваем центральные блоки):

пояснение: чисто для примера дивы col-lg-3 переделал на col-sm-3 дабы в примере кода видно было как работает.

**upd:**

Если необходимо приглушить данный функционал на мобильных устройствах, оберните код проверкой ширины вьюпорта (например для устройства с разрешением <= 480px)

```
if ($(window).width() > 481) {
```

```js
  var $flexitCollection = $('.flexit'),
  maxHeight = 0;
  $flexitCollection.each(function(i, el) {
    maxHeight = (maxHeight < $(el).outerHeight()) ? $(el).outerHeight() : maxHeight;
  });
  $flexitCollection.outerHeight(maxHeight);
```

```css
.compl2 {
  margin-top: 20px; }

.compl-block {
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: #e10886;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #e10886; }

.compl__title2 {
  font-size: 35px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-bottom: 0; }

.compl2__text {
  padding-top: 0;
  border-top: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-transform: none;
  margin-bottom: 0; }
  .compl2__text span {
    text-transform: capitalize; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="compl2">
<div class="container">
<div class="row no-gutters a">
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <h2 class="compl__title2 compl-block">
    комплекс 1
  </h2>
  <p class="compl-block compl2__text flexit">
    <span>ноги</span> полностью, <br>
    глубокое бикини, <br>
    ягодицы, пальцы ног
  </p>
  <p class="compl-block compl2__text compl2__text2">
    4500
  </p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <h2 class="compl__title2 compl-block">
    комплекс 2
  </h2>
  <p class="compl-block compl2__text flexit">
    <span>ноги</span> полностью, <br>
    глубокое бикини, <br>
    подмышечные <br>впадины, пальцы ног
  </p>
  <p class="compl-block compl2__text compl2__text2">
    4000
  </p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <h2 class="compl__title2 compl-block">
    комплекс 1
  </h2>
  <p class="compl-block compl2__text flexit">
    <span>глубокое</span> бикини, <br>
    подмышечные<br>  впадины голени, 
    с, коленом
  </p>
  <p class="compl-block compl2__text compl2__text2">
    3000
  </p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <h2 class="compl__title2 compl-block">
    комплекс 1
  </h2>
  <p class="compl-block compl2__text flexit">
    <span>глубокое</span> бикини, <br>
    подмышечные
    впадины
  </p>
  <p class="compl-block compl2__text compl2__text2">
    2100
  </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: спасибо, у меня на десктопе колонки разной высоты; надо сделать колонки одинаковой высоты на десктопе; а на меньших разрешениях надо чтобы было как у меня в коде если нажать кнопку выполнить код

Comment: извините не увидел ваши пояснения, спасибо за помощь

Comment: у меня ничего не выходит :(

Comment: извините сам изучаю js отключил свой код заработало :)